# Scoping with Nested Functions in Python

Tags: python, scope

This question is similar to others asked on here, but after reading the answers I'm not grasping it and would appreciate further guidance.

While sketching new code I find myself adding a lot of statements like:

```
print('var=')
pprint(var)
```

It became tedious always writing that, so I thought I could make it into a function.  Since I want to print the variable name on the preceding line, I tried:

```
def dbp(var):
    eval('print(\'{0}=\')'.format(var))
    eval('pprint({0})'.format(var))
```

so then I do do things like:

```
foo = 'bar'
dbp('foo')
```

which prints

```
foo=
'bar'
```

This is all great, but when I go to use it in a function things get messed up.  For example, doing

```
def f():
    a = ['123']
    dbp('a')
f()
```

raises a NameError (NameError: name 'a' is not defined).

My expectation was that dbp() would have read access to anything in f()'s scope, but clearly it doesn't.  Can someone explain why?

Also, better ways of printing a variable's name followed by its formatted contents are also appreciated.

Comment: `foo` is local to the module `dbp()` is in the module scope so has access to the modules scope. `a` is local to `f()` `dbp()` has no access to `f()`s scope. If you were to `def dbp()` inside `f()` then it would have access to `f()`s scope. A hack to this problem is to pass `locals()` in as well and then you can use `locals()['a']` and you wouldn't need the `eval()` statements.

Comment: In both cases, you pass a string and eval will try and print that variable. If that variable is in eval's scope, it is printed. Otherwise, it isn't.

Comment: Why do you `eval()` the first `print()`? Wouldn't `print('{0}='.format(var))` do?

Comment: Re: print() vs eval(print()) - I do this because it is late and I am tired :)  You're right, the first print should have been a real print.

Comment: Re: explanation of why dbp() has no access to a - So the scoping is defined relative to where dbp() is _defined_ rather than where it is called.  Interesting - I was thinking any function call saw scope relative to where it was called.  Thanks!  Now I'm wondering how I've never noticed this before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should look at other ways to doing this.
The `logging` module is a really good habit to get into, and you can turn off and on debug output.
Python 3.6 has `f''` strings so you would simplify this to:

```
pprint(f'var=\n{var}`)`
```

However, here's an example (not recommended) using `locals()`:

```
In []:
def dbp(var, l):
    print('{}='.format(var))
    pprint(l[var])

def f():
    a = 1
    dbp('a', locals())
f()

Out[]:
a=
1
```

Comment: Agreed re: logging.  I used it once a long time ago and forgot about it.  It always felt like overkill for minor debug printing, but minor printing always seems to turn into major printing anyway... I should just build the habit.

Answer (score -1):

first of all, id like to say that eval is a high security risk for whoever is going to be running that code.

However, if you absolutely must, you can do this.

```
def dbp(var):
    env = {'var': var}

    # Adding global variables to the enviroment
    env.update(globals())

    eval("print('{0}=')".format(var))
    eval('pprint(var)', env)   

def f():
    a = ['123']
    dbp('a')
```

you can then do

```
>>> f()
a=
'a'
```

Comment: `f()`s scope is not in `globals()`.

Comment: Looks like nonsense. Doesn't print `['123']`.

Comment: @AChampion you're right, I overlooked that. Your answer is the correct one.